# Finding the latest record using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to pull the latest record for people in a table where they each have multiple records. I need to base this on a combination of a number field (which is easier) combined with a text field (which could be one of three different words).

Here is an abbreviated example of what some of the data looks like:

```
personID | Year | Term
      01 | 2012 | Fall
      01 | 2013 | Spring
      01 | 2013 | Summer
      06 | 2012 | Spring
      06 | 2012 | Fall
      11 | 2013 | Fall
```

I need to run a select statement that will pull the latest record for each personID based on the latest year, and then within that year, by term (earliest is spring, then summer, then fall). So hopefully the end result would look like this:

```
personID | Year | Term
      01 | 2013 | Summer
      06 | 2012 | Fall
      11 | 2013 | Fall
```

I know how to use max(year) and making it equal to the year field in the table but that's only doing that one column. When someone has more than one record in that year it pulls *each* term for that year and I can't order it because it's text and not even alphabetical. If anyone could help me with this that would be amazing. Let me know if I need to give more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate sequential number in every group ordered by `YEAR` and `Term`.

```
SELECT  personID, year, Term
FROM
(
    SELECT  personID, year, Term,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personID ORDER BY YEAR DESC,
                                CASE WHEN Term = 'spring' THEN 1
                                    WHEN Term = 'summer' THEN 2
                                    ELSE 3 END DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
) a
WHERE   a.rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8cd76/1)